# Display Listview inside another Listview's EmptyDataTemplate

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, web-controls

Is there any way to display listview as another listview's empty data template. I just put it like following. But it wont display the listview or it's emptydata text. only displaying 'empty data first listview' text

```
<asp:ListView ID="searchResults" runat="server" ItemPlaceholderID="placeholder">
    <EmptyDataTemplate>
        empty data first listview
        <asp:ListView ID="suggestions" runat="server" ItemPlaceholderID="placeholder" DataSource="<%#Model.SearchSuggestions %>">
            <EmptyDataTemplate>
                empty data second listview</EmptyDataTemplate>
            <LayoutTemplate>
                <span class="suggestionList">
                    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="placeholder" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
                </span>
            </LayoutTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%# Container.DataItem %>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <ItemSeparatorTemplate>
                ,</ItemSeparatorTemplate>
        </asp:ListView>
    </EmptyDataTemplate>
    <LayoutTemplate>
       *************
    </LayoutTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

Comment: if you remove the string "empty data first listview" does it still not work?

Comment: nope its not working. i just put it to check whether empty template iw working or not.

Answer (score 0):

I copy and pasted your code and was able to get it to work by manually databinding it in the codebehind. The only modification I made to your aspx code was to remove the reference to the model, to simplify setting it up on my end. I have included my ugly/overly simple test code below.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    searchResults.DataBind();
    searchResults.Controls[0].DataBind();
}
```